# Excel/VBA Environ("username") error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that contains a range of model inputs that get loaded into a SQL Server database. Part of this process involves building an audit trail of who updated what and when - I record the user and machine name as well as timestamp.

Within my VBA code, I have the following:

user = VBA.environ$("username")

This is running on a Win7 machine, with Office 2013.

When I run the code, it all works fine, but when someone in production runs it (on the same machine, but they are logged in, not me), it falls over on the line above. I have used variations of the above (user = environ("username"), user = environ$("username")) but always with the same outcome - it works for me, but not for others.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are:

```
Sub Test()
    With CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        Debug.Print .UserName
        Debug.Print .ComputerName
        Debug.Print .UserDomain
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I will try it Monday and see if it works.

Comment: that also worked for me. Many thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 5):

The environment variables are unreliable

1. The user can edit the value to anything they want
2. The user can delete the environment variables.

Try one of these **API** methods.

**Option 1**

```
Private Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" _
(ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Sub Sample()
    Dim lpBuff As String * 25
    Dim ret As Long, UserName As String

    ret = GetUserName(lpBuff, 25)
    UserName = Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1)

    MsgBox UserName
End Sub
```

**Option 2**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetEnvironmentVariable Lib _
"kernel32" Alias "GetEnvironmentVariableA" _
(ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpBuffer As String, _
ByVal nSize As Long) As Long


Private Sub Sample()
    Dim strUserName As String * 255
    Dim x As Integer

    x = GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME", strUserName, Len(strUserName))
    If x > 0 Then
        x = InStr(strUserName, vbNullChar)
        If x > 0 Then
            MsgBox (Left$(strUserName, x - 1))
        Else
            MsgBox (Left$(strUserName, x))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for that. I will give it a try on Monday and let you know how it goes ...

Comment: I used your option 2 above and it worked perfectly for capturing username and computer name.

Comment: Case by case. If i'm creating a temporary environment variable and using it immediately, then there's no chance for the user to touch it.

Answer (score 1):

I always use `Application.UserName` because it's almost always better - `environ$("username")` could give you something like "john~smith" whereas `Application.UserName` would give you "John Smith"

Comment: `Application.UserName` can be changed in the Excel General Options, so I would consider it even more unreliable http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/09/10/allow-only-specific-user-to-change-excel-list/

Answer (score 1):

I always use

```
Environ("USERPROFILE")
```

But generally speaking I need to reference that person's desktop quite a bit.