# not able to update access table field using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a userform in access which submits the data to a table, there are two fields in table which I want to get populated  automatically whenever user makes a new entry in form. I am using the below vba code with that form :

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function GetUserName() As String
 Dim obj1 As Object
 Set obj1 = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
 GetUserName = DLookup("[BAFUser]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & obj1.UserName & "'")
 Set obj1 = Nothing

End Function

Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
 Owner2 = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
 AdvisorName = GetUserName

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
 Me.DataForm.Form.Recordset.MoveLast

End Sub

Private Sub SaveBtn_Click()
 RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
 Me.Requery
 Me.DataForm.Form.Recordset.MoveLast
End Sub
```

I am able to get the value in "owner" field but not in "AdvisorName" field.
What can be the possible reason behind this ?
is there any mistake in my code or is there any better method of doing this ?

Comment: `AdvisorName = GetUserName` What does this do?

Comment: it will save the value of GetUserName variable in AdvisorName column in table, well that code is not working, I tried to save AdvisorName = "hello world" its not saving it either. but its saving in Owner.

Comment: That isn't the way you save something to a table. I don't know how Owner is receiving anything because that is incorrect as well. You are saving those values to variables only. They're also privately scoped, so the value disappears almost immediately and never interacts with your form. Could you provide more detail about your form? Are the controls bound to your table?

Comment: `RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` this line commits the form's current record to the table, so I assume it is bound, which is superfluous because a bound form does this automatically.

Comment: Yes the table is bound. So what is the correct way of saving a value in column upon each entry ?@MoondogsMaDawg Sorry I am fairly new to Access, but I can give you all the details you require to help me.

Comment: You don't need code to do so. Access will do it automatically for you after the current record is moved. So you enter data into your form, then press a navigation button to move to a different record (new, old, it doesn't matter). At that point Access will append your table with the control values on your form. Otherwise, you need to write a sql statement, manipulate a querydef, or use a recordset to save a record to a table (all of which use a sql statement). Search for "vba execute sql append" and you should find plenty of examples, but it shouldn't be necessary to do in your case.

Comment: Is AdvisorName a form control? Or were you trying to get this value into the table in code only?

Comment: No I want to set this value using code not form controls, I do not want user to see this control it should get submitted automaticall on each entryy for all users.

Comment: I have disabled the navigation buttons and other buttons, Its a command button which is saving the data as you can see the code SaveBtn_Click()

Comment: Ok can you add the table name, columns, types to your question. I'm happy to edit the code.

Comment: Table Name - Mau_con I have many Columns but I to submit data via code only for two columns "AdvisorName" , "Owner" , both are text  type.and I have a variable in my code "GetUserName", VBA should check the Value of "GetUserName" everytime before submitting the entry and saving the value of this variable to column "AdvisorName".

Comment: hope I was clear with the explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should commit both values to your table using a querydef. This is my preferred approach but there are other ways to do it as well. The qdf represents a sql string that can accept parameters from code. We are inserting the values of our variables directly into the sql string.

I copied the code from the save button to re-establish the form state after entry. This should bring the last record back up, but it will depend on the cursortype of the recordset whether the saved record is represented or not (it might go backwards).

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim Owner2 As String
    Dim AdvisorName As String

    Owner2 = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
    AdvisorName = GetUserName

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "INSERT INTO Mau_con (Owner, AdvisorName) VALUES ('" & Owner2 & "', '" & AdvisorName & "')")
    qdf.Execute
    Me.Requery
    Me.DataForm.Form.Recordset.MoveLast
    Set qdf = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: It is giving compiler error, what can be the reason ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot the first qdf argument (the query name, which doesn't exist, so I used an empty string).

Comment: Also, no double-quotes should be in the sql string. I updated the answer again.

Comment: Now its not giving error but is also not saving anything in AdvsiorName and Owner field

Comment: Step through the code. Do the variables have values before `qdf.Execute`? Set a breakpoint on `qdf.Execute` and when it stops type: `?qdf.sql` into the immediate window and post what is returned.

Comment: sorry I am not sure how to do that, lemme just tweak into this and I will tell what is gives

Comment: sorry I am not able to find a relevant article to see how to do it, can you please explain

Comment: Open VBE, find this code, and to the left of `qdf.Execute` left-click the side of the window. A red dot should appear. Now save the code, enter form view on your form, and trigger the code to run. When it does, the VBE will pop up when it hits the red dot. Then type `?qdf.sql` into the part of the VBE that says "Immediate Window" and press enter. It should respond with something like: "INSERT INTO Mau_con (Owner, AdvisorName) VALUES ('xxxx', 'xxxx')". Paste that output here.

Comment: A breakpoint looks like [this](http://d2r5da613aq50s.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/485743.image7.jpg)

Comment: okay after saving the red dot, I went to my form again and as soon as I typed anything in form it took me to VBA with a yellow arrow on red dot but no window pop up to write anything, do I need to write it beside the arrow now ?

Comment: No the immediate window isn't open. Ctrl + G should make it pop up

Comment: OK I got its, the result after it says compile error : Expected function or variable

Comment: and if i run the immediate wndow without triggering the code it says error 424 : Object required

Comment: The error 424 makes sense, because qdf won't exist if code isn't running. Did you use the question mark in front? `?qdf.sql` What version of Access are you using? Check each of your variables, so in break mode try `?Owner2`, `?AdvisorName`

Comment: yes I used question mark and I am on access 2010, lemme try others too

Comment: Well I tried ?Owner2.sql and ?AdvisorName.sql it returns the same, should I try to type in into the form and let it trigger the code break then I should type ?

Comment: Just do `?Owner2` and `?AdvisorName`. `.Sql` is only a property of the qdf object.

Comment: Yes, activate the code and wait for it to hit the break point, then type in the immediate window.

Comment: if I just type ?Owner or ?AdvisorName it wont work, hitting enter button will just come to the next line.

Comment: That means they are empty! Bingo!

Comment: To test, you can try `?IsNull(AdvisorName)` and it should respond `TRUE`.

Comment: To test your libraries, slap [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39659425/5936117) into a module and run it. Does it print the proper values?

Comment: It returened false with  ?IsNull(AdvisorName)

Comment: What about `?AdvisorName = " "`

Comment: you want me to use that answer in a totally new modul not in this form's module right ?

Comment: It returned false with ?AdvisorName = " "

Comment: You can run it anywhere you want. I usually use a module though to keep the source code clean. Bottom line here is you need to make sure your variables are holding a valid string or the qdf will fail and not write to the table. I don't know why `?qdf.sql` isn't working either. I cannot replicate the issues you are seeing.

Comment: I tried the below code i a test form module it worked :

`Option Compare Database

Public Function GetUserName() As String

 Dim obj1 As Object
 Set obj1 = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
 GetUserName = DLookup("[BAFUser]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & obj1.UserName & "'")
 Set obj1 = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
 Dim AdvisorName As String
 AdvisorName = GetUserName
 MsgBox "Welcome " & AdvisorName
End Sub
`

Comment: sorry its mess but yes its showing the value of AdvisorName in msgbox

Comment: Open query designer in SQL mode, and paste the following while updating the "My.." values with actual values (keep the single quotes): `INSERT INTO Mau_con (Owner, AdvisorName) VALUES ('MyOwner', 'MyAdvisor')`. Then run it. Is the record added to the table?

Comment: it says, cant append all the records in the append query.

Comment: Sounds like we aren't meeting the table requirements then. You said you only want to add two columns, but the table may require more. You need to check each column to see which ones have "required" set to "Yes". If any other columns besides these are required, you will either have to add them to this query or remove the requirement.

Comment: Yeah I am sorry, one of the field was set on required now I have set it to no, and it saved the record succefully in table, I hope we are close to fix this now :)
and yes I have more than 10 fields

Comment: Haha yes me too. Try running the code again, hopefully it will fire. I just hope the form doesn't scramble because that's another can of worms.

Comment: Ok the thing is code worked, thank you so much, but It entered those two fields in 2 lines first and then in the third row I can see the data I entered in form, they are not coming in same row, one more thing I noticed since the time u made me change my code, It refreshes the form automtically once when i try to enter information, shall we try to remove requery ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot this was beforeInsert. It's your code, do whatever you please. I put that there for insurance since I do not know enough about your form  to know how to maintain its state. If it's unnecessary by all means delete it.

Comment: so previosly the data was coming in third line now its coming in second line and in first row i have the value of AdvisorName successfully, so should I use a diffrent function or what ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by second and third line. On your form? I don't know what your form looks like or what it is displaying.

Comment: when i click the submit button it creates a row in table with only AdvisorName and Owner filled and a second row with the details which I put into form, it is creating two rows in table, It is not capturing the data in single row

Comment: do you think I should write my insert query in evernt of submit button click ?

Comment: Ah I gotcha. Can you unbind the form? You can move the code to the save routine but that won't stop the second record. Making the control source for each field empty will prevent the second line, but you'll have to write a routine to save the other fields because you'll lose functionality.

Comment: do I need to write codes for each field then ? I am afraid the more I rely on   VBA code, will increase the chances of user getting error. So whats the best way to do it now ?

Comment: I had another idea last night. Build a hidden form control that calls `GetUserName`. You may need to requery it at certain points, but you can bind it to the table and get rid of the vba that saves the record. Otherwise you will have to decide whether to use a bound or unbound form. Errors with unbound forms really only occur if you don't plan for all eventualities, which makes it more work but much more flexible. Bound forms keep the designs simple and easy, but are a little less flexible. I'd try making a username control first. If you can get it to work, you can use a bound form.

Comment: I actually did the same last night after getting rid of the double row thing, Its working fine now, but Whenever I press the f5 key it losts the value, here is the code I used, 
`Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.AdvisorName2.Value = GetUserName
    Me.DataForm.Form.Recordset.MoveLast

End Sub`

Comment: hm, that's odd. Put a breakpoint in there and make sure `GetUserName` actually fires. I don't see any problem with that code, and f5 definitely fires the Form_Load event when switching from design mode, so I don't see where else it could fail.

Comment: Ok I tried it when I open the form for first time it triggers and stops at the breakpoint, and I checked GetUserName has the desired values as well, but when I refresh the form with f5 button it does not trigger at breakpoint, it does not stops a all,, feels like it is not calling the  Form_Load() on pressing f5, I am confused why is it doing like this, I have asked another question for this, may be we can discuss [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682667/how-to-prevent-f5-key-from-saving-data-from-userform-in-access)