# How to prevent F5 key from saving data from userform in access

Tags: ms-access, userform

I have a bound form in MS Access and I use a submit button to insert the data from form to table. I have around 10 fields in form and even if I fill only 1 field and press the F5 button, it saves the data with just one field. How to stop F5 key from doing this.

Edit -  also when I close the form with partially filled data or if it gets closed accidently or when if i open design mode from there, it collects that partially filled data and then creates an entry, how to stop userform making entries via other means and make it only create record on button click.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should not *stop* the F5 button from doing this, you should stop anything else than your submit button from saving data.

This can be achieved with some VBA code:

<sub>The save button is named cmdSave in this example</sub>

```
Private saveButtonPressed As Boolean

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    saveButtonPressed = True
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End Sub


Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not saveButtonPressed Then
        'Update through other means
        Cancel = True
    End If
    saveButtonPressed = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not saveButtonPressed Then
        'Update through other means
        Cancel = True
    End If
    saveButtonPressed = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I used the above code, but now I am not able to type anything, what could I possibly missed ?

Comment: You probably haven't assigned the close button to the VBA code.

Comment: I dont have a close button, is it necessary ?

Comment: nope, it's not necessary. However, you need to make sure either the changes get undone if the form is closed, or something else happens, because they can't be saved with the current code on a form close

Comment: what should I do now ?

Comment: Well, start by verifying you've bound the close button to the VBA code

Comment: but I dont have a close button, I have a "Save" Button and another button which opens another form without closing this one, how do you want me to verify

Comment: I can't personally debug your database, you will have to figure it out yourself