# VBA: combining an item from an array with a string

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string

im having trouble with some concatenating a string together. i want my out put to look like

```
Sub chkstr()
    whoami = ExecShellCmd("whoami")
    arrWhoami = Split(whoami, "\")
    username = arrWhoami(1)

    Debug.Print "C:\folder_one\foler_two\" & username & "_info.txt"
End Sub
results: C:\folder_one\folder_two\myusername_info.txt
```

but it is returning it the string with a line break like this

```
C:\folder_one\folder_two\myusername
_info.txt
```

any thoughts on how i can get it to results like in the top part

Comment: then try: `username = replace(arrWhoami(1),chr(10),"")`

Comment: Can you share `whoami` string? The extracted `username` should contain an end line character (vbCr, vbLf etc). Otherwise, it is not possible to obtain what you show us. Replacing the character in discussion will solve the problem, but it would be good to understand why such a string, I think...

Comment: Since, you are only using the username part, perhaps this would help deciding how to retrieve a username. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39656844/excel-vba-environusername-error

Comment: Why not use `Environ("username")` to get the user name?

Answer (score 0):

I may be on the wrong track here, but I wonder if you're using a function from [here](https://officetricks.com/execute-shell-read-output-vba/) that looks like this:

```
Public Function ExecShellCmd(FuncExec As String) As String
    Dim wsh As Object, wshOut As Object, sShellOut As String, sShellOutLine As String
    
    'Create object for Shell command execution
    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    'Run Excel VBA shell command and get the output string
    Set wshOut = wsh.exec(FuncExec).stdout

    'Read each line of output from the Shell command & Append to Final Output Message
    While Not wshOut.AtEndOfStream
        sShellOutLine = wshOut.ReadLine
        If sShellOutLine <> "" Then
            sShellOut = sShellOut & sShellOutLine & vbCrLf
        End If
    Wend

    'Return the Output of Command Prompt
    ExecShellCmd = sShellOut
End Function
```

If so, you could refactor it so that it doesn't put the final line feed in in the first place:

```
Public Function ExecShellCmd(FuncExec As String) As String
    Dim wsh As Object, wshOut As Object, sShellOut As String, sShellOutLine As String
    
    'Create object for Shell command execution
    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    'Run Excel VBA shell command and get the output string
    Set wshOut = wsh.exec(FuncExec).stdout

    'Read each line of output from the Shell command & Append to Final Output Message
    While Not wshOut.AtEndOfStream
    
    ' Put new line in only if there is something more to be read
    
        If sShellOut <> "" Then sShellOut = sShellOut & vbCrLf
        sShellOutLine = wshOut.ReadLine
        Debug.Print (sShellOutLine)
        If sShellOutLine <> "" Then
            sShellOut = sShellOut & sShellOutLine
        End If
    Wend

    'Return the Output of Command Prompt
    ExecShellCmd = sShellOut
End Function
```